# Sha256 function in PHP with init?

Tags: php, function, init, sha256

Are there any function in PHP where you can set [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256_.28a_SHA-2_variant.29_pseudocode) state for sha256?

I would like to translate this javascript to php https://github.com/jwhitehorn/jsMiner/blob/4fcdd9042a69b309035dfe9c9ddf716119831a16/engine.js#L149-165

Comment: Are you looking for [Incremental Hashing](http://php.net/function.hash-init.php)?

Comment: @Heandel, im not 100% sure :P I just want to translate the javascript to php

Comment: @netcoder, yes probably, but i do not know how to use it in this case.

Comment: you could check and see if this gives the same result: `hash('sha256', pack("H*", $foo))`. this is what i use to do sha256 hashes for hex strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a php sha256 class with init state

https://github.com/codler/Bitcoin-phpMiner/blob/ed2e422a025ebf8555ecd53ce03aad631550b3e7/sha256.php